# Firefox don't use CSS

Tags: css, firefox

I have site [extreme-store.com](http://extreme-store.com/) good working in Chrome but something wrong in Firefox. Main style sheet (layout.css) not used by Firefox. What's wrong?

Comment: From me it does. What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Now it works, see answer below.

P.S. I'm using 31.2.0-r1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="/templates/extreme-store/css/layout.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/extreme-store/css/layout.css">
```

Comment: I am amazed at your powers of observation!